# What do I fill in the space?

Tags: verbs

I don't know what to put in here. What verb use the collocation "on"?
Don't be too eager to _ on a media studies course.

> The kind of people they admire are TV presenters. They look glamorous and they're in the _(public) eye, and a lot of young people _(have) strong desire to be famous. But the vast _(majority) are only going to face disappointment. These jobs are _(in) fact very hard to get. So if you're keen _(on) the idea of such a career, think again. Don't be too eager to __ on a media studies course. You may never get a job from it.

Comment: Hello.  Is there any clue in the context of the question.  There are hundreds of verbs that form phrasal verbs with "on"  Many could fit here: "decide on", "start on", "go on", "build on",  and there are also non phrasal verbs that could have an "on" prepostional phrase: "quit", "pass", "work"  There is no way to answer this question.

Comment: If there's no context, I'll suggest that it is closed to answers.

Comment: enroll would also work, but it's not a phrasal verb, and it is a bit more formal.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is the paragraph that sentence is in, I've omitted some words due to characters limit.
The kind of people they admire are TV presenters. They look glamorous and they're in the _(public) eye, and a lot of young people _(have) strong desire to be famous. But the vast _(majority) are only going to face disappointment. These jobs are _(in) fact very hard to get. So if you're keen _(on) the idea of such a career, think again. Don't be too eager to __ on a media studies course. You may never get a job from it.
@JamesK

Comment: You can [edit] the question instead of writing a comment.  There is no character limit for the question.

Comment: @JamesK.  Yes there is a character limit on questions.

Comment: @Chenmunka There is a lower limit.  There might be an upper limit... But the OP is not going get close to it.  In practice the OP can add all the information in their comment and more by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible answers:  "start on", "decide on", or more formally "enroll on".  It is not possible to decide which is the correct answer.

---

<sub>The paragraph is (IMHO) poor advice.  Media studies is not about becoming a celebrity, but about gaining a critical understanding of media, and there are plenty of jobs that it could lead to.</sub>